# SAP Hana integration with Business One user Accounts Login

Tags: hana, service-layer, sapb1, hana-xs

I have a basic problem with SAP Hana and Integration of it with B1.
I have developed a project for loading data from B1 using calculation and attribute views accessed by xsodata services, and also Insert and Update using xsjs services. Now I want to add login to it, I mean login for b1 users entering their credentials and then be redirected to e.g. their list of activities.

I have configured approperiate service for calling B1 Service Layer "Login" method and it works just fine (it gives back sessionId and other infos). But the problem I have is how to use it in entire project. I mean for example when the user calls a **xsodata** service detect if his/her session has expired before loading data from service and decide to return data or redirect him/her to login page.

And for the sake of security, I want these session checks be done server side, not in the controllers.

It would be pleased if you gave me some samples or just ideas to what to do.